# HttpWebResponse:  Windows service vs. console application

Tags: c#, windows-services, console-application, httpwebresponse, getresponse

I have a problem that I haven't been able to resolve for two days.

In a console app, this code works fine:

```
url="http://www.reuters.com/finance/currencies/quote?srcAmt=1.00&srcCurr=USD&destAmt=&destCurr=ASD&historicalDate=MMddyyyy"
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Timeout = 3000000;

using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
   // ...
}
```

But in my Windows service, `GetResponse()` is throwing the exception, "The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.reuters.com'".

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, maybe I am setting something wrong in `ServiceInstaller`.

Thanks for showing me the right track, but there is an additional issue.

I am working on virtual machine (I have got admin rights, but I have no experience with administration at all).

If I set account in service installer for the user (and give details of my login) then I have problems with the connection to the database (Odbc). Connection open throws me:

```
ERROR [08001] [MERANT][ODBC Sybase driver]
Allocation of a Sybase Open Client Context failed.  
Sybase normally generates a SYBINIT.ERR file containing more specific reasons for failing.\r\n
ERROR [01S00] [MERANT][ODBC Sybase driver]
Invalid attribute in connection string: Port.
```

So if set Account User in `ServiceInstaller` I can't connect to the DB, else if I set Account to LocalSystem I can open connection to DB but I can't use `GetResponse()`.

So the question is, what should I do when everything is placed on Windows Terminal Server?

I suppose that there could be something messed up with admin rights. What could I do to fix this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Service application run under the LocalSystem account by default, whereas your console app runs under your user account, you may therefore be meeting permission problems (windows firewall?)

You should run the service under the administrator account to see if this resolves your issue.